# What is the dimension of an open subset of an affine euclidean space? And why?

Tags: general-topology

My question comes from an exercise from my differential geometry book:

*An open subset $M \subset \mathcal E$ is a smooth manifold of maximal dimension, i.e. $dim(M) = Dim(\mathcal E)$, and - for all p $\in$ M -*

*$T_pM = E$*

I used a restriction to $W = \xi^{-1}(M) $ of a global chart $\xi: R^m \rightarrow \mathcal E $ to proof is a manifold but i'm not sure on how to determine the dimension.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $W = \xi^{-1}(M)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and you have -- in the process of showing that $M$ is a manifold -- constructed a chart $$\xi|_W : W \to M,$$ by (the most common) definition of dimension, the dimension is simply $m$, i.e. the same as that of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Well, i'm lacking what and why is dim(W)=dim(M)=dim($\mathcal E$)

Comment: Perhaps you disagree with the following definition: $M$ is a smooth manifold if for every point $p \in M$, there is an open neighbourhood $U \subseteq M$, an open set $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a "chart" $\xi : W \to M$ satisfying the usual properties. When you have this, then by definition $\mathrm{dim}(M) = n$. In your case, you took $\xi$ to be a chart on $\mathcal{E}$, so $\xi$ is a map defined on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{E})}$. Moreover, $W$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{E})}$, and so $\mathrm{dim}(M) = \mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{E})$.

Comment: I forgot that dimension of a manifold is the dimension of the differential of his chart, therefore the dimension of $R^n \supset W$.